# Soffer, Softer, Soifer

Tags: filing

In reference to the patent: [US2704622](https://www.google.com/patents/US2704622)

Why is it called a "Soffer" when the inventor is named "Softer" or "Soifer" as seen in various locations on the patent?  Which ones are spelling errors and which ones are not.  Were errors like this common back in the day?

Answer (score 1):

This is the result of imperfect optical character recognition of an old patent. Try reviewing the pdf version. Google patents tries to automatically generate a text version of the patent. For old patents that are scanned from paper copies, this is prone to errors.